# Separate vuex stores for component created with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, store, vuex

Imagine three components `First.vue`, `Second.vue` and `Third.vue`
They share some info, to manage all changes and get access to data I use Vuex.
It works perfect. No problem here. To keep `store` clean and tidy, I have modules for every component.

Then, we have a component named `Card.vue`. It is composed of three components, mentioned above.

In `App.vue`, I use v-for directive to create as many `Card`s as needed.

```
<template>
  <div>
     <card v-for="card in cards" :id="card"></card
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   data () {
     return {
        cards: [] // items being dynamically added to this array  
 }
</script>
```

As you understand, when we generate more than one of `Card.vue`, we have several **cards** with the same data. In other words when I change any value in input field of *Card#1*, I commit change to `$store`, and update state everywhere else (in *Card#2*, *Card#3* and so on...) What I need is to separate those Cards data. How can I design my **Vuex** to accomplish that goal.

**Sharing `STATE` and `COMPONENTS`**

`$store`

```
import job from './modules/job'    
import paper from './modules/paper'
import admin from './modules/admin'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
      getters,
      mutations,
      modules: {
        job,
        paper,
        admin
      }
    })
```

I use three modules and keep my getters and mutations in separate js file. Module files have the same structure. For example, `Job.js` is like:

```
const state = {
  paper: {
    paperWidth: null,
    paperHeight: null,
    typeOfPaper: null,

    ...// other state data
  }
}

const getters = {
  paper: state => state.paper
}

const mutations = {
  updatePaper (state, paper) {
    Object.assign(state.paper, paper)
  },

  ...// other local mutations go here


export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

I've no actions. No need as of now.

Three components are `Job.vue`, `Paper.vue` and `Rseults.vue`. They get state and mutations from their respective module and also from global `store`.

```
import {mapMutations, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default {
        computed: {
          ...mapGetters([
            'job',
            'paper',

            ...// other shared mutations from store      
          ])
        },
        methods: {
          ...mapMutations([
            'fourPlusFour',
            'fourPlusZero',
            'updateJob',

            ...// other shared mutations from store  
          ])
        }
      }
```

Comment: You should be using a `:key` value for your card component

Comment: Tried it, doesn't help. 'cause my getters in Card 1, Card 2 and in any other Card generated are referring to the same state object. I think some kind of modules for Card 1 and Card 2 will fix this issue. But my mind stuck.

Comment: Yeah if you don't want all of your card components to reflect the same data, you shouldn't point them all to the global state. Not sure what your vuex data is like, but it probably would make more sense to move the state module for each `First`, `Second`, and `Third` component out of vuex and into the respective component.

Comment: But either way, you should have a `:key` value for any components rendered with `v-for`. [In Vue 2.2.0+ it's required](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for).

Comment: Yeah, I added `:key`. Concerning modules, the main problem is that initially there is one global store. And it's fine. Later, I add component on the fly. That means that somehow that new component should create its copy of `$store`. I mean, the hard to fix part is not in module separation, but in generating not only HTML with its js-behaviour but also `$store` for that new instance. I believe there should be an elegant solution. Vuex should handle `v-for`.

Comment: what about state: {cards: []} and than you pass e.g. the v-for index to the card object and to update you do state.cards.findIndex(card => card.index === index)

Comment: Can you share what you `state` consists of and what the other 3 components are?

Comment: Added state and 3 components.